# Geo location using python

Tags: python

I have an assignment to read in a csv file into a dictionary and then query the dictionary for coordinate values based on a few given zipcodes. then return if the zipcodes are within 50miles of the "center" zipcode. I'm having a lot of trouble converting the coordinates in radians. Also if anyone can point me in the right direction to find if they are within 50 miles. Here is my code so far:

```
import sys
import csv
import math  

dicts = {}
origin =[]
ziplist = ['12481', '10001', '12203', '10303', '12561']
center ='12401'
def getLatRad(latitude):
    return float(latitude) * (math.pi/180.0)
def getLongRad(longitude):
    return float(longitude) * (math.pi/180.0)
def getnearbylist():
    try:
        f = open("zips.csv")
        csvParser = csv.reader(f)
        for row in csvParser:
            zipcode= row[0].strip()
            latitude= row[2].replace('"', '').strip()
            longitude=row[3].replace('"', '').strip()
            dicts[zipcode] = {'latitude': latitude, 'longitude':longitude}

        matched = {match: dicts[match] for match in ziplist if match in dicts}

        for k in matched:
            latRad2 = getLatRad(k[1])
            longRad2 = getLongRad(k[2])
            print latRad2
            print longRad2

        if center in dicts:
            origin ={}
            origin = dicts[center]
            latRad1 = getLatRad(origin[1])
            longRad1 = getLongRad(origin[2])
            print latRad1
    except ValueError:
        pass





getnearbylist()
```

The origin[x] isnt working and i dont have a very vast understanding of python so would someone be able to help me work out how to convert these coordinates.

**Sample Data:**

```
"zipcode", "state abbreviation", "latitude", "longitude", "city", "state"
"35004", "AL", " 33.606379", " -86.50249", "Moody", "Alabama"
"35005", "AL", " 33.592585", " -86.95969", "Adamsville", "Alabama"
"35006", "AL", " 33.451714", " -87.23957", "Adger", "Alabama"
"35007", "AL", " 33.232422", " -86.80871", "Alabaster", "Alabama"
"35010", "AL", " 32.903432", " -85.92669", "Alexander City", "Alabama"
"35014", "AL", " 33.355960", " -86.27720", "Alpine", "Alabama"
"35016", "AL", " 34.323715", " -86.49278", "Arab", "Alabama"
"35019", "AL", " 34.292540", " -86.63505", "Baileyton", "Alabama"
```

Comment: can you post a few lines of the CSV?

Comment: You can't exactly expect us to help you if we don't know what info you have and what you don't.

Comment: You have to elaborate on "isn't working".  What behavior do you expect, and what behavior are you seeing? You're 1000x more likely to receive great help if you hone your question into the form "Here's what I want to do, here's what's happening, and here's the **relevant** code".  Also, what version of python are you using?

Comment: I figured mostly everythign out, i just need the function to return the zipcodes that are within the threshhold http://pastebin.com/nDzn06tS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
import csv
from math import radians,sin,cos,asin,sqrt

def haversine(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2,radius=3959):
    lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2 = map(radians, [lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2])
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    return 2*radius*asin(sqrt( sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*sin(dlon/2)**2 ))

class Zipcodes():
    def __init__(self, fname="zips.csv"):
        self.zips = {}
        with open(fname) as inf:
            r = csv.reader(inf)
            header = r.next()   # discard header row
            for row in r:
                zip = row[0].strip()
                lat = float(row[2].replace('"','').strip())
                lon = float(row[3].replace('"','').strip())
                self.zips[zip] = (lat,lon)
    def dist(self, zip1, zip2):
        try:
            lat1, lon1 = self.zips[zip1]
            lat2, lon2 = self.zips[zip2]
            return haversine(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2)
        except KeyError:
            return 15000.0

def main():
    z = Zipcodes()

    # you figure out what goes here!
    print z.dist('35004','35007')

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```